# "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded..."

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, post-feedback

[image]

Recorded where, in how much detail, and for what purpose? Seen this numerous times over the last few weeks while trying to upvote questions on a Stack site I'd just recently joined, and it always got me curious, so I decided to finally ask.

Comment: Recorded in a database, but not very accessible really. If you have 10,000+ rep you can see some aggregate results of such votes if you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson Actually, the feature you're thinking of no longer exists. At this point anyone (even people who have no account anywhere on the network) can view the feedback by composing a query on SEDE.